# Lebesgue integral of non-measurable function which is equal a.e to a measurable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Usually we define the Lebesgue integral for functions $X\to [0,\infty]$ which are measurable (i.e preimage of every Borel set in $[-\infty,\infty]$ lies in $\mathcal{A}$). Now, if $F,G:X\to [0,\infty]$ are measurable and $F=G$, $\mu$-a.e (i.e there is a $Z\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mu(Z)=0$ and $F=G$ on $Z^c$) then it is easy to show that $\int_X F\, d\mu = \int_X G \, d\mu$.

Consider the following definition:

> **Definition.**
>
> Suppose $f:X\to [0,\infty]$ is a function which is equal $\mu$-a.e to a measurable function $F:X\to [0,\infty]$. Then we define $\int_X f \, d\mu := \int_X F \, d\mu$, where on the RHS we have the standard Lebesgue integral of a non-negative measurable function.
>
> This is certainly well-defined, because if $G$ is another such function then $F=G$, $\mu$-a.e, so that by my previous remark, this definition assigns the same value to $\int_X f \, d\mu$.

**Questions:**

1. Is making this definition ill-advised/not recommended for any reason?
2. Of course this becomes a non-issue if we're dealing with a complete measure space, so my question is whether we lose any generality by always working with the completion of a measure space? Are there any situations where we rather work with an incomplete measure space as opposed to its completion?

---

The context for these questions is that I've been studying the Bochner integral for Banach-space valued functions, and when seeing how this works out when the Banach space is $E\in \{\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{C}\}$, I noticed that there are quite a few additional technicalities regarding measure zero sets. This arises because a $\mu$-integrable function $f:X\to E$, i.e a function which is the $\mu$-a.e pointwise limit of a Cauchy-sequence (relative to $\mathcal{L}^1$-seminorm) of $\mu$-simple functions, is not necessarily measurable in the preimage sense.

$f$ is only equal $\mu$-a.e to a function  $\tilde{f}:X\to E$ which is preimage-measurable, and this extra complication makes the statement of several theorems (which try to relate Bochner integrability and Lebesgue integrability, and the values of their integrals) kind of awkward.

Comment: Any measure space can be completed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes, I know that, but part of my question is also that whether there are any situations we might not want to work with the completion of a measure space (one thing I can think of is that a not-so-nice feature is that composition of Lebesgue measurable functions is not necessarily Lebesgue measurable, whereas if we work with the incomplete space, composition of Borel-measurable functions is Borel-measurable).

Comment: I am not sure what your final goal might be. However, there is a theory for the integration of non measurable functions. For probabilists working in the area of Empirical Processes that is a "way of life". The theory is quite interesting as one introduces outer integrals and what is called measurable majorants. That would surely emcompass your situation as well and would therefore be more general. See for instance, van der Vaart and Wellner, Weak Convergence of Empirical Processes, chapter 1. Also M.M. Rao  Measure Theory and Integration deals with this type of situations.